# Generate log of variable and append to existing dataset

Tags: mathematica

I just started using Mathematica and I hope that someone can help me with a small piece of code:

- I have a variable "X" in a dataset A.
- I want to create a new variable called "logX" which is the log of the variable X and add it as a new column in dataset A using "append" in Mathematica if possible.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"x" -> 5|>, <|"x" -> 10|>}]
Append[#, "lx" -> Log[#x]] & /@ ds
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it is not working. I tried to write this code which in my view should work but it is not. Maybe you can tell where it fails? dataA1 = dataA1[All, Append[#, 
"logclientrevenues" -->log[#clientrevenues] ]&]

Comment: @LasseHolm Please try it exactly as I showed you: `Append[#, "logclientrevenues" -> Log[#clientrevenues]] & /@ dataA1`.  Note that `Log` cannot be spelled `log`.

Comment: I tried running your suggested code by writing the following: dataA1 = dataA1["clientrevenues" -> 5|>, <|"clientrevenues" -> 10|>}]
Append[#, "logclientrevenues" -> Log[#clientrevenues]] & /@ dataA1 but it is still not working. Either way, thanks for your inputs!

Comment: @LasseHolm What you wrote has many errors.  Copy and paste what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> dataset[MapIndexed[Append[#1, "Column2" -> Log[[1, 1]]] &]]

Where column $1$ is your data and the new column is column $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it is not working. I tried to write this code which in my view should work but it is not. Maybe you can tell where it fails? dataA1 = dataA1[All, Append[#, 
"logclientrevenues" -->log[#clientrevenues] ]&]